# Why does this stream act this way?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have this section of code within a class:

```
using (StreamReader Stream = new StreamReader(CombinedFile))
                using (JsonTextReader JsonStream = new JsonTextReader(Stream)) 
                {
                    string JsonString = Stream.ReadToEnd();
                    Stream.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonString);
                    try
                    {
                        InsertList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<int, object>>>(JsonString);
                        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------" + InsertList.Count);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------" + ex);
                    }
                }
```

and for some reason it will only work if I include the try/catch. I will see the InsertList.Count increment in my console, and the follow-on to the script will continue. If I remove the try/catch and just have it as:

```
using (StreamReader Stream = new StreamReader(CombinedFile))
                using (JsonTextReader JsonStream = new JsonTextReader(Stream)) 
                {
                    string JsonString = Stream.ReadToEnd();
                    Stream.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonString);
                    InsertList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<int, object>>>(JsonString);
                    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------" + InsertList.Count);
                }
```

I will not get output to the console. The using() statement is wrapped in a larger try/catch, no errors occur and the method continues on.

I cannot for the life of me understand why.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger to see what happens? Considering the only thing inside that `try` block that can actually cause an error is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, I think it's safe to assume it's having trouble deserializing the object.

Comment: A [repro] would certainly help here.

Comment: Are you really really really sure you are seeing the InsertList.Count incremented in the console and not some exception message text? And as a side note: What is the nonsense with the JsonTextReader there in your code?

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace yes i am sure.... The jsontextreader was something i had been following in a question on SO and started to peel it back to see why this wasnt working like i thought it should

Comment: @Jesse i had just put that try/catch in there because anything south of it didnt seem to run. But i would assume it wouldnt operate differently whether it is wrapped within a try/catch or not

Comment: Well, i guess then you will have to provide a self-contained, complete and minimal code example runnable as-is which exhibits the issue. The code in your question has no suspicious bits that could explain what you seem to have observed...

Comment: @user9472341 The purpose of a `try..catch` is to `try` a block of code and `catch` exceptions. The only reason it would make the code behave differently is if it was throwing an exception. As I said before, since the only thing in your `try` block that can reasonably throw an error is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, it's probably safe to assume it's having trouble deserializing the object. Start there.